# Counting swaps in a sorting method

Tags: java, compare, counter

So I have this assignment where I have to compare a bunch of sorting methods and count the number of comparisons and the number of copies each algorithm performs.I have already created my sorting methods but have never made a counter before. My question is how would I declare a counter and where would I put one in my code?

Sorry completely forgot, kinda overwhelmed right now. I'm using java.

I know I would put like counter++ before the swap or comparison I'm just a little lost on the syntax

Comment: You should probably tell us what language you're using and how you think you should start.

Comment: Perhaps if you could show the sorting code for one sort type we might be able to suggest where best to put the counters? If you're at the stage of writing and comparing sorting code, then it is hard to see the difficulty that you might have inserting counters for the `swap` and `comparison` operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your sorting algorithms in an independent class, kept separate from your main app.  Your counters can be field variables of that class.  That way, you can run your sort, and follow up by retrieving the metrics you gathered.

```
MySortAlgorithms sorter=new MySortAlgorithms();
ArrayList example=sorter.quickSort(ArrayList arr);
System.out.println("Swaps=" + sorter.getSwapCount());
```

Answer (score 0):

Counter can be a simple static variable in your class . Isn't it? Just add to it everytime you want to swap.

```
Class ObjectToBeSorted{
   static int numberOfSwaps;

   public static increment swap(){
     numberOfSwaps++
   }

   public static clearSwaps (){

      numberOfSwaps = 0;
   }


}
```